# Images not rendering randomly on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Image of the bug is appearing only at one place i.e. x = 0,y = 0.

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var bugSmashed = 0;

//rendering background image
function renderImage()
{
    var backImage = new Image();
    backImage.src = "jungle.jpg"
    backImage.onload = function(){
        c.drawImage(backImage,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)}
}
renderImage();

//Making a bug
class Bug {
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    renderBug(){
        var bugImage = new Image();
        bugImage.src = "bug.png";
        bugImage.onload = function(){
            c.drawImage(bugImage,this.x,this.y,65,65)}}
}
```

Trying to make the bug appear randomly on the canvas

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
        var x = 32+Math.random()*(canvas.width-64);
        var y = 32+Math.random()*(canvas.height-64);
        var aBug = new Bug(x,y);
        aBug.renderBug();}, 2000);
```

I am sure I am missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I recommend you `console.log(this.x, this.y)` right before you do `c.drawImage(...)`. I suspect `this.x` and/or `this.y` are `NaN`, which will cause them to resolve to 0 when used as values in canvas draw operations.

Comment: when i am calling  ```console.log(this.x, this.y)``` just before ```bugImage.onload(..)``` x and y have values but when i call ```console.log(this.x, this.y)``` inside the ```bugImage.onload(..)``` just before ```c.drawImage(...)``` they are 0,0 .I am not sure Why is that happening.

Answer (score 1):

I found your problem: `this` changes its meaning inside a `function`. So when you use:

```
function(){c.drawImage(bugImage,this.x,this.y,65,65)}
```

`this` no longer refers to `aBug`! (It will instead refer to the global `Window` object.) You can use fat-arrow syntax instead (which preserves `this`):

```
() => c.drawImage(bugImage,this.x,this.y,65,65)
```

Another really ugly way which I discourage you from using is by creating a new reference to `this`, and then using that reference in your function:

```
let that = this;
function(){ c.drawImage(bugImage, that.x, that.y, 65, 65); };
```

Or you can simplify your code to have it gloss over `onload` logic, allowing you to avoid wrapping `c.drawImage` in a function in the first place (note the square which appears is a publicly addressable image):

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

//Making a bug
let bugImg = new Image();
bugImg.src = "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.pXD0MAw4LeAcVrt3qRiEfwAAAA?pid=ImgDet&rs=1";
class Bug {
    constructor(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    renderBug(){
        c.drawImage(bugImg, this.x, this.y, 65, 65);
    }
}

var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var x = 32 + Math.random()* (canvas.width - 64);
  var y = 32 + Math.random()* (canvas.height - 64);
  var aBug = new Bug(x, y);
  aBug.renderBug();
}, 500);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```